# Unity Invalid rank specifier: expected',' or ']' on One Dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I do not see anything wrong with my code but I keep getting the following error:

Invalid rank specifier: expected',' or ']'

I commented everything out except for the an empty start() and update() function which do not have anything to do with anything and it definitely works without it.

```
string str1 = "whateves";
string str2 = "bla";
string str3 = "wer";
string str4 = "gaaaah";

string[] alice = new string[4];

alice[1] = "wehe";
alice[1] = str2;
alice[2] = str3;
alice[3] = str4; 
int[] directions = new int[4];
```

Anyone have any ideas what's goin on and how to fix this?
It basically breaks at the alice[1] = "wehe".  It doesn't seem to recognize that alice is an array at all and keeps thinking I'm trying to declare something.  This is incredibly frustrating.

Update! Fixed, Dr. Koch's answer worked.

My code was in the format

```
public class dialog_text : MonoBehaviour {

[the code I posted]

void start(){
}

void update(){
}

}
```

And I moved it (and changed it to reflect what i was using it for) like so:

```
public class dialog_text : MonoBehaviour {

string str1 = "whateves";
string str2 = "bla";
string str3 = "wer";
string str4 = "gaaaah";

string[] alice =  {"lkwahtelkhekwtakwet", "wetnjdnkfakjberkt", "lwhtiowkltrnf"};
int[] directions = new int[4];
//set the array of this object that stores the text
string[] textarr;

//set the array of this object that stores the next place to go to
int[] nextarr; 



void start(){
    textarr = alice;
    nextarr = directions;
}


void update(){
}

}
```

So it works for now!  I still don't really get why doing something like 
alice = {str1, str2, str3, str4} not in start() breaks it, but all is well.

Comment: Works just fine for me... the only thing to point out is you're never assigning anything to alice[0], but rather overwriting alice[1]'s "wehe" with str2's "bla" (and str1 is unused). Can you provide more details?

Comment: Sounds like you might have gotten an unprintable character into your source code file or something. Certainly the code you posted would not cause the error you describe. Try just deleting and retyping the whole line.

Comment: Is this within a method, or in a class declaration? Where *exactly* is it complaining, within that line? Can you show the whole of the class?

Comment: @Dasanko   I'm doing it in C# as a assembly script in Unity attached to a Text game object.  this code is located within the class definition, outside of start() and update().  The answer DrKoch put resolved the problem for me, but I am still confused as to why this is (new to C#).

Comment: @BookLover That's just how the language is. You can read a bit more about C# fields here: [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Put *declarations* at the class level, but *initializations* in the constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    string[] alice = new string[4];

    public MyClass()
    {
        alice[1] = "wehe";
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   It's fixed now.  May I ask, is this a weird C# scripting thing, or is this a weird Unity thing? I'm used to Java, where you can simply initialize in the class, so...

Comment: This is according the C# language specs.